# Create a json from given list of filenames in unix script

Tags: json, linux, shell, unix, command-line

Hello I am trying to write unix script/command where I have to list out all filenames from given directory with filename format string-{number}.txt(eg: filename-1.txt,filename-2.txt) from which I have to form a json object. any pointers would be helpful.

```
 [{
        "filenumber": "1",
        "name": "filename-1.txt"
    },
    {
        "filenumber": "2",
        "name": "filename-2.txt"
    }
 ]
```

In the above json file-number should be read from {number} format of the each filename

Comment: That doesn't look like valid JSON (incorrect quoting); and would you really want the numbers to be strings? Have you tried something, and where did you encounter problems?

Comment: Now the field name for the filenames is inconsistent: Should it be "url" or "name"?

Comment: Hello Sorry for the incorrect json it should be corrected now.

Comment: I am trying to use  
echo "[" >> test.json
for dir in "${array[@]}"; do
     
        file=$(find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname '*.txt' | awk "NR==$i")
        [[ -n $file ]] && 
                printf '%b{ "filename": "%s" }' $prefix "$file" >> test.json
        prefix=",\n"
done
echo
echo "]" >> test.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried with multiple examples to achieve exact use case of mine and finally found this working fine exactly how I wanted Thanks

```
 for file in $(ls *.txt); do file_version=$(echo $file | sed 's/\(^.*-\)\(.*\)\(.txt.*$\)/\2/'); jq -n --arg name "$file_version" --arg path "$file" '{name: $name, name: $path}'; done | jq -n '.urls |= [inputs]'
```

Answer (score 1):

A single call to jq should suffice :

```
shopt -s extglob
printf "%s\0" *-+([0-9]).txt | \
    jq -sR 'split("\u0000") |
            map({filenumber:capture(".*-(?<n>.*)\\.txt").n,
                 name:.})'
```

Answer (score 1):

Very easy for the command-line tool [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel) and its integrated EXPath File Module:

```
$ xidel -se '
  array{
    for $x in file:list(.,false(),"*.txt")
    return {
      "filenumber":extract($x,"(\d+)\.txt",1),
      "name":$x
    }
  }
'
```

Answer (score 0):

Intuitively, I'd say you can do this with `jq`. However, in practice I've rarely been able to achieve what I wanted with `jq` :-)

With some lunch break puzzling, I've come up with this beauty:

```
ls | jq -R '{filenumber:input_line_number, name:.}' | jq -s .
```

Instead of `ls` you could use any other command that produces a newline separated list of strings.

Comment: is there some way I can grab filenumber from the name of the file after - for eg: filenumber as 1 for filename-1.txt

Comment: That's an entirely different problem and it shows the shortcomings of specification by example. If you want to extract a number from the filename, you need to specify exactly what happens with files without numbers, with multiple numbers, numbers written as words, etc. All that is missing from your requirements.

Comment: I always have files with that format name-{number}.txt. I want to extract that number.

Comment: Then please edit your question to reflect this. And I don't think `jq` will be the right tool then, you may need to write some code in a real programming language.